# Scala: Overridden value parent code is run but value is not assigned at parent

Tags: scala, inheritance, constructor, object-initialization

Running the code below:

```
class Parent {
  val value = {
    println("Setting value in parent")
    "ParentVal"
  }
  println(s"Parent value is ${value}")
}

class Child extends Parent {
  override val value = {
    println("Setting value in child")
    "ChildVal"
  }
  println(s"Child value is ${value}")
}

new Child
```

Produces this output:

```
Setting value in parent
Parent value is null
Setting value in child
Child value is ChildVal
```

So the code associated with the parent value assignment is run, however the value is not really assigned at the parent. Afterwards the child code runs and it assigns the value as expected.

Could someone explain the chain of events here at a lower level?

Comment: base class's construct will be firstly called and then the extended ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think about `val` as if it were a combination of a private member variable without setters + a getter method. If you rewrite your code without `val`s, it would be something like this:

```
class Parent {
  private[this] var parentValue = {
    println("Setting value in parent")
    "ParentVal"
  }
  def value: String = parentValue
  println(s"Parent value is ${value}")
}

class Child extends Parent {
  private[this] var childValue = {
    println("Setting value in child")
    "ChildVal"
  }
  override def value = childValue
  println(s"Child value is ${value}")
}

new Child
```

Just as the original, it prints:

```
Setting value in parent
Parent value is null
Setting value in child
Child value is ChildVal
```

This is because the parent constructor invokes the *method* `value`, but this method is overridden by `def value = childValue`. The returned `childValue` is `null`, because when the parent constructor is invoked, the child constructor has not been invoked yet.

You can read more about [object initialization order here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html).

---

Related answers:

1. [Why does implement abstract method using val and call from superclass in val expression return NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51426770/2707792).
2. [Assertion with `require` in abstract superclass creates NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51745845/assertions-in-abstract-superclass-scala-creating-npe/51746736#51746736)