# Why does implement abstract method using val and call from superclass in val expression return NullPointerException

Tags: scala, object-initialization

I have an abstract class with an unimplemented method `numbers` that returns a list of numbers, and this method is used in another val property initialization:

```
abstract class Foo {
  val calcNumbers = numbers.map(calc)
  def numbers: List[Double]
}
```

The implementing class implements using a val expression:

```
class MainFoo extends Foo {
  val numbers = List(1,2,3)
}
```

This compiles fine, but at run time it throws a NullPointerException and it points to the line of `val calcNumbers`:

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[error] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
...
[error] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
...
```

However when I changed the implemented method to def, it works:

```
def numbers = List(1,2,3)
```

Why is that? Does it have something to do with initialization order? How can this be avoided in the future as there is no compile time error/warning? How does Scala allow this unsafe operation?

Comment: missing `s` in `number`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Scala, what is an "early initializer"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712468/in-scala-what-is-an-early-initializer)

Comment: @HüseyinZengin that seems somehow too vaguely related, no? Another non-duplicate: [Scala initialization order of vals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568049/scala-initialization-order-of-vals) (there, the OP simply swapped order of `val`s, no abstract classes, no def-by-val override). A somewhat better duplicate: [NPE when overriding parameterless method with a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313143/null-pointer-exception-when-overriding-a-parameterless-method-with-a-field), but the answer could be much more detailed.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Well you are right about the question itself not being a exact duplicate but this question is basically a result of early init. and the answer is perfectly covering this question IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what your code attempts to do when it initializes `MainFoo`:

1. Allocate a block of memory, with enough space for `val calcNumbers` and `val numbers`, initially set to `0`.
2. Run the initializer of the base class `Foo`, where it attempts to invoke `numbers.map` while initializing `calcNumbers`.
3. Run the initializer of the child class `MainFoo`, where it initializes `numbers` to `List(1, 2, 3)`.

Since `numbers` is not initialized yet when you try to access it in `val calcNumbers = ...`, you get a `NullPointerException`.

Possible workarounds:

1. Make `numbers` in `MainFoo` a `def`
2. Make `numbers` in `MainFoo` a `lazy val`
3. Make `calcNumbers` in `Foo` a `def`
4. Make `calcNumbers` in `Foo` a `lazy val`

Every workaround prevents that an eager value initialization invokes `numbers.map` on a non-initialized value `numbers`.

The [FAQ](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html) offers a few other solutions, and it also mentions the (costly) compiler flag `-Xcheckinit`.

---

You might also find these related answers useful:

1. [Scala overridden value: parent code is run but value is not assigned at parent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50705388/2707792).
2. [Assertion with `require` in abstract superclass creates NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51745845/assertions-in-abstract-superclass-scala-creating-npe/51746736#51746736)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Though it strikes me when Scala allows this loophole/pitfall without default warning about that...

Comment: @texasbruce Well, *object initialization* is just hard. The fact that it works at all in languages with inheritance, traits, exceptions, garbage collection, class-loaders, built-in singletons, and multithreading is a miracle...

Comment: It should be disallowed to override a method using `val` in Scala to avoid this issue. Only allow `def` and `lazy val`